# Is it possible to push triggers from the amp-analytics tag to GTM?

Tags: triggers, google-tag-manager, amp-html, amp-analytics

I'm trying to figure out if I can push a click event from `AMP` to `GTM`. From what I've seen, the only option is to setup events in `GTM` to watch for the clicks *because GTM creates the triggers(?)*. I don't know the actual answer, that is my best guess.
For instance, I'm was hoping to accomplish something like this. I'd want to be able to click this link and pass some vars with it.

```
<a href="url" title="lorem" id="this-trigger">Lorem Ipsum</a>
///
<amp-analytics>
    <script type="application/json">
        {
            "vars": {
                "lorem": "foo bar baz"
            },
            "triggers": {
                "anchorClicks": {
                    "on": "click",
                    "selector": "#this-trigger",
                    "request": "event",
                    "vars": {
                        "site_events": "lorem click",
                        "lorem": "lorem click"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

But the only thing that has worked is using GTM's triggers to watch for a click.
Is it possible to utilize `amp-analytic`'s JSON triggers with GTM?

=====

Update:
So I was missing the request property in the JSON. Thanks to @SomewhereDave.
I was also thinking about it wrong, this essentially bypasses GTM and goes straight to the analytics.

```
<a href="url" title="lorem" id="this-trigger">Lorem Ipsum</a>
///
<amp-analytics>
<script type="application/json">
{
  "requests: {
    "trigger1": "<The Request URL for the pixel>"
  }
  "vars": {
    "lorem": "foo bar baz"
  },
  "triggers": {
    "anchorClicks": {
      "on": "click",
      "selector": "#this-trigger",
      "request": "trigger1",
      "vars": {
        "site_events": "lorem click",
        "lorem": "lorem click"
      }
      }
  }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

Comment: For anyone else who ends up here, I was missing the requests property that the triggers send the data through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a click trigger with GTM the container snippet waits for click events to bubble up to the document node. This is called Auto Event Tracking by Google Tag Manager. So you could say that GTM creates the trigger.

To use hard coded event tracking follow the instructions [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-analytics). Just search for click trigger. A little bit more generic than in your example, your code should look something like this:

```
<amp-analytics>
  <script type="application/json">
      "vars": {
          "id1": "#this-trigger"
      },
      "triggers": {
        "trackAnchorClicks": {
          "on": "click",
          "selector": "a, ${id1}",
          "request": "event",
          "vars": {
            "eventId": "clickOnAnyAnchor",
            "eventCategory": "This is the category of the event",
            "eventAction":"This is the action tied to the event",
            "eventLabel":"The label tied to the event"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

Values defined within `vars: {}` are picked up by Google Analytics, if they are known. Here eventCategory, eventAction and eventLabel would populate the respective event fields. Notice that above's example is hard coded tracking.

Unknown vars values will be ignored. If GTM is implemented with AMP key-value-pairs can be freely choosen and picked up by AMP variables then from within GTM (Simply navigate to the variables tab and create an AMP variable with the vars key).

However, you first need to create a GTM AMP Container and load your container like this:

```
<amp-analytics config="https://www.googletagmanager.com/amp.json?id=GTM-1A2B3C&gtm.url=SOURCE_URL" data-credentials="include">
  <script type="application/json">
  {
    "vars": {
      "eventId": "clickOnAnyAnchor"
    }
  }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

A very well written article about using GTM with AMP [here](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/accelerated-mobile-pages-via-google-tag-manager/)

Comment: Thanks for the response Dave, I'll give this a run. The reason I wanted to see if I could use the JSON triggers is because you can pass vars with them, if I understand the documentation correctly. From what I can gather, if one uses the GTM dashboard for clicks, then the only data available are the vars you pass on page load.

Comment: @SomewherDave For other folks who end up here, can you make some adjustments to your code sample?   The event has double quotes. And could you explain where base came from in your example?

Comment: @JasonLydon I made my example more generic, since you updated your own question with a specifc answer and added a small snippet for GTM as well as a thorough source